# A package import works when running script directly but not when that script is imported by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have this situation:

```
main_script.py
tools/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

In `a.py` I have the following

```
import argparse
from b import b_func

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('a')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    b_func(args.a)

def a_func(x):
    return x 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I want to run this, everything works fine: `python tools/a.py foo`

However, in my `main_script.py` file, I am importing `a.py`:

```
import argparse
from a import a_func

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('a')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    a_func(args.a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now if I run `python main_script.py foo` I will get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

I can correct this by doing `from tools.b import b_func` inside `a.py` but then I won't be able to do `python a.py foo` anymore.

Why is this happening and how can I correct it? How can I make sure these references are all correct?

Comment: guess that should be `from tools.b import b_func`. both modules `a` and `b` are in the `tools` package.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: If I do that, I get this error when I run the `a.py` script: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools'` (when I call it as `python tools/a.py foo`)

Comment: ah, if you want to be able to do that you could try a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports): `from .b import b_func`. haven't tried. but it may not be the cleanest design to want to run scripts from inside modules...

Answer (score 1):

Python looks for packages and modules in the pythonpath. By default, that is the directory in which the main script is, but it can be set explicitly in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

You are using two py files as the main script in different cases, and those two files are in different directories. That is, first of all, a bad setup. It would IMO be best to have only one entry point, it at least to have all entry points on the top level directory and to never import one from another.

That mean, you should not run `python a.py`, but instead create a `run_a.py` in the parent directory and import `tools.a` from there.

If you still want to keep the file structure as it is, then you need to change two things:

1. change the import from `from b import b_func` to `from tools.b import b_func`
2. set PYTHONPATH to point at the parent directory when running `a`, e.g. in Linux: `PYTHONPATH=.. python a.py`.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem,In a large majority of cases these errors occur because Python interpreter fails to resolve the module name in sys.path (the place Python looks in after module look up fails in both sys.modules and the Standard Library. and the final solution was to put all the code into a folder, package it with `setuptools`, then use any way to reference and run it works fine.[setuptools document](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html).Run `pip install -e .` in the same directory as `pyproject.toml` in the current python environment